# Placing cursor in the center of a child div - mousemove event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div that can be placed anywhere inside another div. I am able to do this with jquery mousemove event. However it is not quite working. I am trying to get the mouse cursor to be in the center of the moving div.   I set these css attributes inline with jquery `'top': relY + 30,'left': relX + 10` but no luck. As mention I am trying to get the cursor in the middle of the div. The user can only place the moving inside the parent div called `middle-side empty`. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/24/)

I am trying to accomplish something similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqebpaov/

Jquery:

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    $('<div />', {
        class: 'draggable ui-widget-content',
        text: $('textarea').val(),
        appendTo: '.middle-side',
        draggable: {
            containment: 'parent'
        }
    }).addClass('placement');



    $('.middle-side').parent().mousemove(function(e){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var relX = e.pageX - offset.left;
        var relY = e.pageY - offset.top;
        $('.placement').css({'top': relY + 30,'left': relX + 10, 'position': 'absolute'});
    })

});

$('.middle-side').on('click', function(e){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var relX = e.pageX - offset.left;
    var relY = e.pageY - offset.top;
    $('.placement').css({'top': relY,'left': relX, 'position': 'absolute' });
    $(this).off("mousemove").find('.placement').removeClass('placement')    
});
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="middle-side empty"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a fun question. I updated a lot of your Javascript, and set up my own [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wolfet/uLs3e9qs/1/). 
With this setup you should be able to resize the boxes to any height/width combination and it will work as expected. You can check out the [JSFIDDLE link](http://jsfiddle.net/wolfet/uLs3e9qs/1/), but here is the updated Javascript also:

```
    $('#button').click(function (e) {
        $('<div />', {
            class: 'draggable ui-widget-content',
            text: $('textarea').val(),
            appendTo: '.middle-side',
            draggable: {
                containment: 'parent'
            }
        }).addClass('placement');



        $('.middle-side').parent().mousemove(function(e){
            var offset = $(this).offset(),
                relX = e.pageX,
                relY = e.pageY,
                $dvPlacement = $('.placement'),
                pWidth = $dvPlacement.outerWidth(),
                pHeight = $dvPlacement.outerHeight(),
                $dvOutBox = $('.middle-side'),
                oWidth = $dvOutBox.outerWidth(),
                oHeight = $dvOutBox.outerHeight(),
                centerY = relY - pHeight / 2,
                centerX = relX - pWidth / 2,
                topBorder = $dvOutBox.offset().top,
                bottomBorder = $dvOutBox.offset().top + oHeight,
                leftBorder = $dvOutBox.offset().left,
                rightBorder = $dvOutBox.offset().left + oWidth;

            $dvPlacement.css({'top': centerY + pHeight > bottomBorder ? bottomBorder - pHeight :
                                      centerY < topBorder ? topBorder :
                                      centerY,
                              'left': centerX + pWidth > rightBorder ? rightBorder - pWidth : 
                                      centerX < leftBorder ? leftBorder :
                                      centerX,
                              'position': 'absolute'
                             });
        })

    });

    $('.middle-side').on('click', function(e){            
        $(this).off("mousemove").find('.placement').removeClass('placement')    
    });
```

Comment: This is great. I understand this much better. Plus, this is compatible as you mentioned with any div size. Would it be possible to set up some overlay on the temp `.placement` that said "place inside here"?

Comment: I updated the JSFIDDLE, and added a fade in/out "place inside here" to the larger square.

Comment: Perfect! I will probably need to make the fade in/out on the jquery side

Answer (score 1):

Change the placement offset to

```
$('.placement').css({'top': relY + 30,'left': relX - 75 , 'position': 'absolute'});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/25/)

Comment: Yes the offset centers the cursor with your code. But it allows the newly created div to be placed outside the parent div.